# next.js 12.3.1 API Call to Mailchimp - 400 Bad Request

Tags: api, next.js, mailchimp, newsletter

just started on my coding journey and as with these things, sometimes you come across a problem that you are unable to solve it despite multiple hours and attempts..

If anyone could have a look at my code and let me know where I'm going wrong - I have a sneaky suspicion that it's to do with the await fetch call, but I may be wrong.

Thanks in advance.

The component is being imported to index.jsx as, this is the code for my "Contact" component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Contact() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const subscribeUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const res = await fetch('/api/subscribeUser', {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: inputRef.current.value,
      }),

      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },

      method: 'POST',
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-[150px] bg-gray-100/70 text-black/70">
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center pt-2">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-center text-sm md:text-2xl">
          Sign up to the Newsletter...
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center w-full">
        <form onSubmit={subscribeUser}>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email-input"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Your email here"
            ref={inputRef}
            required
            autoCapitalize="off"
            autoCorrect="off"
            autoFill="off"
            className="border min-w-[280px] py-2 px-2 text-center"
          />
          <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
            <button
              type="submit"
              value=""
              name="subscribe"
              className="px-4 py-1 mt-2 bg-gray-200 border border-black/40 text-gray-900 text-lg transition-colors duration-700 transform hover:bg-gray-500 hover:text-gray-100"
            >
              Subscribe
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the api/subscribeUser I am trying to call:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;

  console.log({ email });

  if (!email) {
    return res.status(200).json({ error: '*** Email is required ***' });
  }

  try {
    const AUDIENCE_ID = process.env.MAILCHIMP_AUDIENCE_ID;
    const API_KEY = process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY;
    const DATACENTER = process.env.MAILCHIMP_API_SERVER;
    const data = {
      email_address: email,
      status: 'subscribed',
    };

    const response = await fetch(
      `https://${DATACENTER}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/${AUDIENCE_ID}/members`,

      {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
          Authorization: `apikey ${API_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
      }
    );

    if (response.status >= 400) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error:
          'There was an error subscribing to the newsletter, please try again with a different email address.',
      });
    }
    return res.status(201).json({ error: '' });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message || error.toString() });
  }
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: Have you verified that all your environment variables (`process.env.*`) are set and populated? According to [the API docs](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/fundamentals/#connecting-to-the-api), API keys and OAuth tokens are used the same way – what happens if you change your `Authorization` header's value from `apikey ${API_KEY}` to `Bearer ${API_KEY}`?

Comment: Thank you for the response Mark. I changed the header's value as you suggested to Bearer ${API_KEY} , however the error kept moving down the script and is now showing an error 400 - 'There was an error subscribing to the newsletter..' which is triggered from the next if statement.

Comment: I have managed to create an API that works within the dev environment but upon merging with the main branch, it doesn't seem to be able to communicate with mailchimp.